# d3 Click to create circle and click to remove

Tags: javascript, d3.js, click, event-bubbling

I am trying to click on a circle to remove it, but clicking on the canvas will create a circle.

I do want to actually remove the circle and it's object from the data, as opposed to just making it transparent.

On click on a circle calls the function

```
  function removeElement(d) {
    d3.select(this)
      .remove();
  }
```

This function is called with a basic click on the circle,

```
  .on("click", removeElement);
```

I think I'm not correctly distinguishing between clicking on the canvas to create a circle where none exists and clicking on an existing circle to remove it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  .active {
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width: 2px;
  }
</style>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    radius = 32;

  var data = [{
      x: 100,
      y: 200
    },
    {
      x: 200,
      y: 300
    },
    {
      x: 300,
      y: 200
    },
    {
      x: 400,
      y: 300
    }
  ];

  var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
      return d.x_pos
    })]).range([0, width]);

  svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return d.y;
    })
    .attr("r", radius)
    .style("fill", "lightblue")
    .attr('id', function(d, i) {
      return 'rect_' + i;
    })
    .call(d3.drag()
      .on("start", dragstarted)
      .on("drag", dragged)
      .on("end", dragended))
    .on("click", removeElement);

  svg.on("click", function() {
    var coords = d3.mouse(this);

    var newData = {
      x: d3.event.x,
      y: d3.event.y
    };

    data.push(newData);

    svg.selectAll("circle") // For new circle, go through the update process
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return d.y;
      })
      .attr("r", radius)
      .style("fill", "red")
      .attr('id', function(d, i) {
        return 'circle_' + i;
      })
      .call(d3.drag()
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended))
      .on("click", removeElement);
  })

  function dragstarted(d) {
    d3.select(this).raise().classed("active", true);
  }

  function dragged(d) {
    d3.select(this)
      .attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x)
      .attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);
  }

  function dragended(d) {
    d3.select(this)
      .classed("active", false);
  }

  function removeElement(d) {
    // need to remove this object from data
    d3.select(this)
      .remove();
  }
</script>
```

This question is an extension of the question [D3 remove circle on dbclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46384860/d3-remove-circle-on-dbclick)

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code right now is that, if you click on a blue circle, it will both delete that circle and create a new, red circle. That happens because the event bubbles up to the SVG parent element.

An easy solution is doing this inside the `removeElement` function:

```
d3.event.stopPropagation();
```

As the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) explains, `stopPropagation`...

> ... prevents further propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases.

Here is the code with that change:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  .active {
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width: 2px;
  }
</style>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    radius = 32;

  var data = [{
      x: 100,
      y: 200
    },
    {
      x: 200,
      y: 300
    },
    {
      x: 300,
      y: 200
    },
    {
      x: 400,
      y: 300
    }
  ];

  var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
      return d.x_pos
    })]).range([0, width]);

  svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return d.y;
    })
    .attr("r", radius)
    .style("fill", "lightblue")
    .attr('id', function(d, i) {
      return 'rect_' + i;
    })
    .call(d3.drag()
      .on("start", dragstarted)
      .on("drag", dragged)
      .on("end", dragended))
    .on("click", removeElement);

  svg.on("click", function() {
    var coords = d3.mouse(this);

    var newData = {
      x: d3.event.x,
      y: d3.event.y
    };

    data.push(newData);

    svg.selectAll("circle") // For new circle, go through the update process
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return d.y;
      })
      .attr("r", radius)
      .style("fill", "red")
      .attr('id', function(d, i) {
        return 'circle_' + i;
      })
      .call(d3.drag()
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended))
      .on("click", removeElement);
  })

  function dragstarted(d) {
    d3.select(this).raise().classed("active", true);
  }

  function dragged(d) {
    d3.select(this)
      .attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x)
      .attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);
  }

  function dragended(d) {
    d3.select(this)
      .classed("active", false);
  }

  function removeElement(d) {
    d3.event.stopPropagation();
    // need to remove this object from data
    d3.select(this)
      .remove();
  }
</script>
```

PS: As you probably know by now, I'm not a big fan of answering *different* problems in the same question (which is something that I always advise OPs to avoid). Therefore, I'm not dealing with the data issue, that is, removing the data associated with the clicked element. You can always ask *another* question... it's free!

Comment: I understand and agree, one issue at a time. I'm sure you have detected many potential issues here. So next I will try to remove data as well as the circle. What I am ultimately trying to create is a dynamic multiple slider on to which sliders can be added and removed. So I will use rectangles all with the same y-axis value and they will not overlap or be created if they are too close. I'm far from this now. I think this could be very useful generally.