# D3.js removing data on rect click

Tags: d3.js, slider, removeall

With a lot of [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46390307/d3-click-to-create-circle-and-click-to-remove) I've been able to click on rectangles to remove them.

But how can I also remove the data? Currently there is some strange behaviour, such as previously deleted rectangles reappearing and creation of a rectangle being in a different position to the click. I think all these are caused by the fact that the data is not being deleted.

I thought perhaps .exit() might work, but it doesn't.

Here's a working snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  .active {
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width: 2px;
  }
</style>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    radius = 32;

  var data = [{
      x: 100,
      y: 200
    },
    {
      x: 200,
      y: 300
    },
    {
      x: 300,
      y: 200
    },
    {
      x: 400,
      y: 300
    }
  ];

  var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
      return d.x_pos
    })]).range([0, width]);

  svg.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 100)
    .attr("y", 250)
    .attr("rx", 2)
    .attr("ry", 2)
    .attr("height", 6)
    .attr("width", 800)
    .style("fill", "grey");

  svg.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 102)
    .attr("y", 252)
    .attr("rx", 2)
    .attr("ry", 2)
    .attr("height", 2)
    .attr("width", 796)
    .style("fill", "black");

  svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr("y", 200)
    .attr("height", 100)
    .attr("width", 15)
    .style("fill", "lightblue")
    .attr('id', function(d, i) {
      return 'rect_' + i;
    })
    .attr("rx", 6)
    .attr("ry", 6)
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .call(d3.drag()
      .on("start", dragstarted)
      .on("drag", dragged)
      .on("end", dragended))
    .on("click", removeElement);

  svg.on("click", function() {
    var coords = d3.mouse(this);

    var newData = {
      x: d3.event.x,
      y: d3.event.y
    };

    data.push(newData);

    svg.selectAll("rect")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr("y", 200)
      .attr("height", 100)
      .attr("width", 15)
      .style("fill", "steelblue")
      .attr('id', function(d, i) {
        return 'circle_' + i;
      })
      .attr("rx", 6)
      .attr("ry", 6)
      .attr("stroke-width", 2)
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .call(d3.drag()
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended))
      .on("click", removeElement);
  })

  function dragstarted(d) {
    d3.select(this).raise().classed("active", true);
  }

  function dragged(d) {
    d3.select(this)
      .attr("x", d.x = d3.event.x)
    // .attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);
  }

  function dragended(d) {
    d3.select(this)
      .classed("active", false);
  }

  function removeElement(d) {
    d3.event.stopPropagation();
    d3.select(this)
      .remove();
  }
</script>
```

This question is a follow on from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46390307/d3-click-to-create-circle-and-click-to-remove]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your data array has 4 elements, but you are appending only 2 rectangles. That happens because you are selecting previously existent rectangles in that SVG. Therefore, instead of:

```
svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
```

It should be:

```
svg.selectAll(null)
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
```

Back to your question:

D3 has methods to manipulate elements based on data, but not to manipulate data based on elements.

Thus, you have to change the data array yourself. For instance, inside `removeElement`:

```
function removeElement(d) {
    data = data.filter(function(e){
        return e != d;
    });
};
```

Here is your code with those changes:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  .active {
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width: 2px;
  }
</style>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    radius = 32;

  var data = [{
      x: 100,
      y: 200
    },
    {
      x: 200,
      y: 300
    },
    {
      x: 300,
      y: 200
    },
    {
      x: 400,
      y: 300
    }
  ];

  var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
      return d.x_pos
    })]).range([0, width]);

  svg.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 100)
    .attr("y", 250)
    .attr("rx", 2)
    .attr("ry", 2)
    .attr("height", 6)
    .attr("width", 800)
    .style("fill", "grey");

  svg.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 102)
    .attr("y", 252)
    .attr("rx", 2)
    .attr("ry", 2)
    .attr("height", 2)
    .attr("width", 796)
    .style("fill", "black");

  svg.selectAll(null)
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr("y", 200)
    .attr("height", 100)
    .attr("width", 15)
    .style("fill", "lightblue")
    .attr('id', function(d, i) {
      return 'rect_' + i;
    })
    .attr("rx", 6)
    .attr("ry", 6)
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .call(d3.drag()
      .on("start", dragstarted)
      .on("drag", dragged)
      .on("end", dragended))
    .on("click", removeElement);

  svg.on("click", function() {
    var coords = d3.mouse(this);

    var newData = {
      x: d3.event.x,
      y: d3.event.y
    };

    data.push(newData);

    svg.selectAll("rect")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr("y", 200)
      .attr("height", 100)
      .attr("width", 15)
      .style("fill", "steelblue")
      .attr('id', function(d, i) {
        return 'circle_' + i;
      })
      .attr("rx", 6)
      .attr("ry", 6)
      .attr("stroke-width", 2)
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .call(d3.drag()
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended))
      .on("click", removeElement);
  })

  function dragstarted(d) {
    d3.select(this).raise().classed("active", true);
  }

  function dragged(d) {
    d3.select(this)
      .attr("x", d.x = d3.event.x)
    // .attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);
  }

  function dragended(d) {
    d3.select(this)
      .classed("active", false);
  }

  function removeElement(d) {
    d3.event.stopPropagation();
    data = data.filter(function(e){
    return e != d;
    });
    d3.select(this)
      .remove();
  }
</script>
```